# How to multiplex a stream in rust using sinks and tokio?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I would like to split a stream in Rust, but I'd like to do it idiomatically without side effects in my stream functions.

This is what I have now where I pipe the stream result into a `for_each`

```
let (sender, receiver) tokio::sync::broadcast::channel(1);
let mut base_stream = inf_async_stream_gen().await
     .map(function1)
     .for_each(|x| { 
         let inner_sender = sender.clone();
         async move { inner_sender.send(x); }
     });


let stream_1 = BroadcastStream::new(receiver.resubscribe());
let stream_2 = BroadcastStream::new(receiver.resubscribe());
```

But this feels a little bit odd.  Isn't receiver conceptually a `Sink` (despite not implementing the trait)?

Comment: I suppose I'm kinda asking, why don't the tokio sync structs implement the sink traits

Comment: `tokio::io::Sink` is a struct, not a trait.

Comment: There was a trait of that name in older versions of `tokio`, prior to version 1.0.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [`async_channel`](https://crates.io/crates/async-channel) which sends to one listener instead of all listeners? Either way I'm a bit confused, what exactly is wrong with your current implementation?

Comment: @PeterHall https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.31/futures/sink/trait.Sink.html

Comment: @Rol That's a very old version of that crate. The only external crate you mentioned in your question is Tokio, which also used to have a `Sink` trait, but there has only been a struct since tokio 1.0.